# If statement with both AND and OR Java

Tags: java

I have a (maybe) really basic question about if statements. If I do something like this:

```
if (i == 0 && j == 2 || i == 2 && j ==0) {
    ...
}
```

Then what will happen? Something like `if (i == 0 and j == 1) OR (i == 1 and j== 0)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look up what operator [precedence](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/) in java is. 
So yes, it *should* be evaluated as `if (i == 0 and j == 1) OR (i == 1 and j== 0)`. 
 Question is - do you really want to *rely* on that? I would personally use explicit parenthesis for two reasons:

1. Human readability: anyone(and you when you review your code after few months) see what will will happen without looking up the precedence
2. Compilers can go crazy and you never know on which compiler you will compile it later. Even though compilers *should* do something, it does not mean they *will* do it.

Answer (score 0):

Think of AND as a multiplication and OR as an addition (which they kind of are). Same precedence rules apply.

But if you have a complicated expression, it's better to add parenthesis anyway -- the more readable, the better. And for extra readability, assign the conditions to variables with reasonable names (in your case, it could be `isFirstColumn` and `isFirstRow`)